# Pass dictionary of data to MVC view from controller "synchronously"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

my view show results for multiple cases, So I have about three type of results panel

and each result should show all items that match with result panel type

- I make a partial view to display each one item
- make a for loop to display all items in each result panel
- a view with three result panel
- each panel - Coded as html div - have the partial view for sub items

What I'm thinking to do is to find away to pass a dictionary with type string as key and list of my items - List - and in each partial control call pass a dictionary item with the kind of panel like

```
<%= Html.Partial("myPartialControl",myDictionary["KindOfPanel"] %>
```

So how could pass that dictionary to my view synchronously?
is there any good idea for this issue specially the hole view should be refreshed each 5 second ! like doing it with json or any ajaxing solution.

Comment: I may be missing something, but can't you simply pass the dictionary as an argument to View() in your controller?

Comment: Yes I can, but sorry for missing synchronously word in the question

Comment: Do you mean asynchronously? I suppose you want to load the content of a partial view asynchronously after the page has been loaded into the browser, right?

Comment: No I need to synchronously refreshing the content of the page each 5 second without reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

The word is asynchronously.

If you want to update just a portion of the page without reloading the whole page, then that is done asynchronously with AJAX.

If in the first case you have a view that does this (based on above)

```
...bla
<div id="my-container">
   <%= Html.Partial("myPartialControl",myDictionary["KindOfPanel"] %>
</div>
```

Then create an action that looks something like this in your controller:

```
public ActionResult MyPartialControl()
{
    return PartialView("myPartialControl", theData);
}
```

Then add the following JQuery function and trigger when you want:

```
 $('.my-trigger').click(function(){
      $.get('@Url.Action("MyPartialControl")', function(data) {
         $('#my-container').html(data); 
      });
 });
```

Written without compiler I haven't tested this, but it should work, obviously fill in the blanks and have a play around, but that is the general idea.